# SQL INSERT INTO random commas appearing

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

One a game I am making I have a saving bug. I have an alert with the PHP message. It gives me an SQL error. The problem is obvious. That last comma before the parentheses shouldn't be there. The question is why is it there? In my code, it isn't.

This is the alert message.

[image: Alert Message]

The statement is like this.

```
> $query2 = "INSERT INTO users VALUES ('$village', $power, $influence, $gold, NULL, $ore, $wood, $food, $honor, $keep, $mine, $sawmill, $farm, $barracks, $tavern, $stables, $temple, $militia, $warriors, $spearmen, $clubmen, $swordsmen, $archers, $vanguards, $legion, $crossbowmen, $knights, $mercs, $mercelites, $bandit1, $bandit2, $bandit3, '$faction', $dwellings, $dwellingscost);";
```

One of my theories was that the dwellingscost variable had a comma at the end. It is posted from an AJAX request. If you need some of that code to decipher just ask.

Comment: Simple ... because of this `$dwellingscost` variable?

Comment: Why do you have `'$village'` in single quotes, but most other things without quotes?  @Rahul Agree completely.

Comment: remove singe quotes arround first $village and make all other variable in the values with quotes

Comment: this is why you should not use string concatenation in queries but use prepared statements instead. Commas in variables doesn't have an effect then.

Comment: @e4c5: `$dwellingscost` doesn't contain a comma, it's evaluating as the empty string `''`.

Comment: the variables with quotes are strings and the ones without are integers, that is how you are supposed to annotate the two datatypes, right?

Comment: No. you have to annotate them through a prepared statement